# Editing SuperTable inside Matrix block

Tags: plugin-development, plugin-supertable

I have a matrix field set up as global (`strategies`).

Inside each matrix block there is a SuperTable (`pairs`)

On each row in the SuperTable there is a lightswitch (`active`)

I need to toggle the lightswitch programatically for each row.

Looking at the SuperTable and Craft docs, I still can't make heads or tails of this. Can anyone help?

Edit

Ended up with a poor man's solution by going directly to the table and editing the column. Would still love to know how to do this "properly, though.

```
$disable = StcThreePairs::find()
    ->where(['elementId' => $pair->id])
    ->one();

$disable->field_active = 0;
$disable->save();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you'll want to update the Super Table Block's content and to do that when in a Matrix field is a little tricky, but it can be done.

```
$matrixBlocks = $entry->matrixField->all();

foreach ($matrixBlocks as $matrixBlock) {
    $superTableBlocks = $matrixBlock->superTableField->all();

    foreach ($superTableBlocks as $superTableBlock) {
        $superTableBlock->setFieldValues(['lightswitchField' => true]);

        Craft::$app->getElements()->saveElement($superTableBlock);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@crawf
This is how I used your code to get and set fields 3 layers deep Supertable->Matrix->supertable

This is on submit in a freeForm form.

Thank you so much!!

```
<?php

namespace modules\establishmentmodule\events;

use craft;
use craft\elements\Entry;
use yii\base\Event;
use Solspace\Freeform\Library\Composer\Components\Form;
use Solspace\Freeform\Events\Forms\SubmitEvent;

class EventsFormEvent {

    public static function init() {
        Event::on(
            Form::class,
            Form::EVENT_SUBMIT,
            function (SubmitEvent $event) {
                $form = $event->getForm();

                if ($form->getHandle() !== 'events') {
                    return;
                }

                // Get the store that's selected
                $store = $form->get('dynamicRecipient');

                // Get all fields needed to set the booking
                $emailAdres = $store->getActualValue($store->getValue());
                $selectedDate = $form->get('eventDate')->getValue();
                $selectedTime = $form->get('eventTime')->getValue();
                $bookerFirstname = $form->get('firstName')->getValue();
                $bookerLastname = $form->get('lastName')->getValue();
                $bookerEmail = $form->get('email')->getValue()[0];
                $bookerPhone = $form->get('phoneNumber')->getValue();

                // Get current Entry
                $entry = Entry::find()->one();

                // loop tru the locations that are connected to this event
                foreach($entry->eventsLocations as $location) {
                    // If this location is the chosen store, get the dates
                    if ($location->location->one()->establishmentEMailAddress === $emailAdres[0]) {
                        $matrixBlocks = $location->eventDate->all();
                        // Loop tru the dates for this location
                        foreach($matrixBlocks as $matrixBlock) {
                            $currentDate = Craft::$app->getFormatter()->asDate(
                                $matrixBlock->date,
                                'short'
                            );

                            // If selected date is current loop date, get available timeslots
                            if ($currentDate === $selectedDate) {
                                $superTableBlocks = $matrixBlock->timeslots->all();
                                foreach($superTableBlocks as $superTableBlock) {
                                    $currentDate = Craft::$app->getFormatter()->asTime(
                                        $superTableBlock->start,
                                        'short'
                                    );
                                    // If selected timeslot is loop start time, set this timeslot to false and fill in the credentials
                                    if ($currentDate === $selectedTime) {
                                        $superTableBlock->setFieldValues(['slot_status' => false]);
                                        $superTableBlock->setFieldValues(['booker_name' => $bookerFirstname . ' ' . $bookerLastname]);
                                        $superTableBlock->setFieldValues(['booker_email' => $bookerEmail]);
                                        $superTableBlock->setFieldValues(['booker_phone' => $bookerPhone]);
                                        // save and we are done.
                                        Craft::$app->getElements()->saveElement($superTableBlock);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        );
    }
}
```